# Can someone not from Saint Helen buy ".sh" domain?

Tags: domains

I am interested in buying a `.sh` domain, but I am not from Saint Helen. Am I able to buy a `.sh` domain and is there any rules or regulations that voids me from buying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no restrictions for .SH domain name registrations
Anyone can register a .SH domain name, just like any top level domains (you don't need to be from Saint Helen for that).

Answer (score 1):

To add to Barnettt's answer:

Some top level domains do have restrictions on who can register. .CA for example, CIRA requires that you meet certain ["Canadian Presence Requirements"](http://cira.ca/sites/default/files/attachment/policies/cprregistrants-en.pdf) ([among a number of other things](http://cira.ca/sites/default/files/attachment/policies/registrantagreement_-_en.pdf)).

.SH however, as Barnettt states, does not require registrants to have any real world relation to Saint Helen ("You can now register your own .SH Domain Name which is available to everybody." - nic.sh)